# Python array of base64 encode and serialized array for WHMCS

Tags: python, php, whmcs

I am trying to add new order in WHMCS.

According to [documentation for AddOrder method](https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/addorder/), it is required to specify an array of base64 encoded serialized array for `customfields` and `configoptions` parameters.

Example of such method in PHP is described in example:

```
        array(
            'action' => 'AddOrder',
            ....
            'customfields' => array(base64_encode(serialize(array("1" => "Google"))), base64_encode(serialize(array("1" => "Google")))),
            'configoptions' => array(base64_encode(serialize(array("1" => 999))), base64_encode(serialize(array("1" => 999)))),
            ....
        )
```

I just wonder how to make similar construction in Python?

Tried to use `pickle` and `base64.encode`, but no success

```
tmp = pickle.dumps({"1": "Google"})
customfields = [base64.b64encode(tmp).decode("utf-8")]
```

Then I pass `customfields` to request body, but no success

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this would work but you could give it a try:
`tmp = base64.b64encode(b'{"1": "Google"}') customfields = [base64.b64encode(tmp).decode("utf-8")]`